# Same binding works for 1 XAML item, but null for another

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, datacontext, converters

The binding for productColumn2 works perfect both ways. When I added a converter for each, productColumn1 called the converter; but always has it's value set to null when loading from observable collection, or value set to product when assigning (but doesn't actually assign observable collection).

Issue has to do with DataContext and LogicalTree. The DataContext for ProductSelectorTextBoxUserControl is itself, and is used for it's own code. I want to be able to bind its 'text' property to my observable collection, as in productColumn2. I so far can't seem to set ProductSelectorTextBoxUserControl DataContext to the DataContext used here.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ObservableCollectionItems, Mode=OneWay}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" >
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="productColumn1" SortMemberPath="Product" >
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <productSelector:ProductSelectorTextBoxUserControl Text="{Binding Path=Product, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" /> 
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="productColumn2" Binding="{Binding Path=Product, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" />            
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Comment: Can you share the code for the converter?

Comment: Getting any binding errors in your output window?

Comment: Have you tried using the converter in `productColumn2`? My initial guess is that `customeTextBoxOfProductType` is not finding the `Product` property which would indicate a problem navigating the logical tree and not finding the `DataGrid.DataContext`.

Comment: @JoelLucsy no binding errors.

Comment: @sellmeadog I previously tried changing binding, and converter never got called

Comment: @JoelLucsy added converter to productColumn2 and it receives correct string, and immediately goes to else statement

Comment: If the converter works in `productColumn2` it's safe to assume that your custom textbox is not able to traverse the logical tree to find the `DataGrid.DataContext`.

Comment: @sellmeadog thanks, been looking into that, I clarified and updated the question above, still have issues, think it may have more to do with bindings and datacontext

Comment: Also there is a Product property in that user control (the one I had previously accidentely recursively set). So right now it is trying to get wrong product property because of datacontext issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @SellMeADog for helping me out on this, however this still took me way way to long to figure out. Final line is:

```
<productSelector:ProductSelectorTextBoxUserControl x:Name="productSelector" Product="{Binding Path=Item.Product, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGridRow, AncestorLevel=1}, Converter={StaticResource productNameToProductConverter}, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" />
```

Key points are RelativeSource DataGridRow, Path is Item(ObservableCollection).Property

If you notice question referred to text and this refers to product, I had to switch to product and add converter. UserControl would then set its own text

Comment: Also UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus was bad idea, and made this 1way, had to remove or default to make 2way for my situation

Answer (score 2):

If `ProductSelectorTextBoxUserControl` has a `DataContext` set to itself, the `Binding` won't be able to find the `Product` property as it doesn't exist. You need to modify your binding so that it knows where to find the `Product` property; something like this may work:

```
<productSelector:ProductSelectorTextBoxUserControl Text="{Binding Path=Product, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" />
```

By adding a `RelativeSource`, you're telling the binding to look for the `Product` property in the `DataGridRow.DataContext`.

**UPDATE**

Have you tried `{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}`? You should be targeting the row and not the grid.

When the `ItemContainerGenerator` creates each `DataGridRow` it sets the row's `DataContext` to the corresponding item in the `ObservableCollectionItems`. So, the logical tree something like this:

- `DataGrid` (DataContext = object that defines `ObservableCollectionItems`)

  - `DataGridRow` (DataContext = `ObservableCollectionItems[0]`)

    - `ProductSelectorTextBoxUserControl` (DataContext = self)
  - `DataGridRow` (DataContext = `ObservableCollectionItems[0]`)

    - `ProductSelectorTextBoxUserControl` (DataContext = self)

The grid's `DataContext` doesn't expose the `Product` property, it's defined on each element in the collection (unless I've missed something). The `Product` property should be in the context of each row.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying how it works, yes I had tried DataGridRow and can't get it to work, I'll post the specific information

Comment: System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Product' property not found on 'object' ''DataGridRow' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=Product; DataItem='DataGridRow' (Name=''); target element is 'ProductSelectorTextBoxUserControl' (Name='productSelector'); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')

|

<productSelector:ProductSelectorTextBoxUserControl x:Name="productSelector" Text="{Binding Path=Product, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" />

Comment: I'm sorry I can't be of more help, but I don't know what else to suggest. Best advice I can offer is to research the effects on data bindings when using a `UserControl` in a `CellTemplate`. The problem could also be in the implementation of your control. It's not typical to set the `DataContext` to the control itself. Not sure why you're doing this but I would suggest redesigning your control so it isn't necessary.

Comment: Haven't got it working yet, but interestingly when I add that RelativeSource to proudctColumn2 it has same binding error

Comment: had to switch RelativeSource to this to work on productColumn2, no binding errors on this on productColumn1, but it still has original problem of not connecting to observable collection. 
<DataGridTextColumn x:Name="productColumn2" Binding="{Binding Path=Item.Product, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGridRow, AncestorLevel=1}, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" />

Comment: Actually put converter back on and it's now getting proper information from observable collection, just not showing it, give me some time, as this is issue with user control hopefully